# Find $\int (f'(x))^2 dx$ and $\int (f''(x))^2 dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to find $\int (f'(x))^2 dx$  and $\int (f''(x))^2 dx$

I tried with the first one.

I believed that $\int (f'(x))^2 dx= f(x)+c\;$

for if I put $u=f(x)$ then $du=f'(x)dx$ I get

$$\int (f'(x))^2 dx= \int u'du=u+c=f(x)+c$$

Surely there must be something wrong here. What is it?.

Then how do I solve $\int (f'(x))^2 dx$ or $\int (f''(x))^2 dx$?

Comment: If you were writing $u(x) = f(x)$, then $u'(x) = f'(x)$ would make sense.  But the substitution is $u=f(x)$ and writing $u'=f'(x)$ does not make sense.

Comment: How do you go from $u = f(x)$ to:
$$
\int (f'(x))^2 \; \mathrm{d}x = \int u' \; \mathrm{d}u
$$
?

Comment: It's sketchy but I said $(f')^2=f' \cdot f' =u' \cdot u'\stackrel{?}{=}u'du$. I know it makes little sense, and as that is all I came up with it's why I asked the main question.

Comment: The problem is "$u'$" still makes reference to $x$ (what is the derivative of $u$ taken with respect to?) when a change of variable should completely get rid of all references to the original variable.